# limit jquery function in specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some jQuery code as following:

```
if ($('.test').length) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].click();
}
```

```html
<div class="one" >
    <a class="test" href="#">click me </a>
</div>
<div class="two">
    <a class="test" href="#">click ? </a>
</div>
```

My function clicks on the `a` with the class name but I have two elements with `.test`. How can I limit my function to only the `.one` div?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.one .test` to select the `a` you want:

```
if ($('.test').length) {
    $('.one .test').click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the click event for the link as below:

```
$('.one .test').on("click", function() {

}
```